# CLPlacemark country property is null

Tags: ios, cllocation

the latest Xcode/SDK iOS download is no longer providing the 'country' string.

```
- (void)GEOLocator
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentCentre.latitude longitude:currentCentre.longitude];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:myLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        // the returned error code is 0
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)error.code);
        // there’s only one entry in the placemarks NSArray
        NSLog(@"placemarks count(%lu)",(unsigned long)[placemarks count]);
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks firstObject];
        // and the country property is null
        NSLog(@"placemark.country(%@)",placemark.country);
    }
    ];
}
```

currentCentre.latitude and currentCentre.longitude is hardcoded to downtown San Francisco: these have been proven to work.

the NSLog output’s are:

2015-08-29 15:47:48.299 MyApp[10128:548448] 0

2015-08-29 15:47:48.299 MyApp[10128:548448] placemarks count(1)

2015-08-29 15:47:48.300 MyApp[10128:548448] placemark.country((null))

this code sequence is about as simple as it gets, yet the latest Xcode/iOS download no longer can tell me what country I’m in?!

if this isn't correct can someone please post the correct way to retrieve 'county' from CLLocation?

Answer (score 0):

the core problem is that in Xcode/Simulator you can set lat/long values in multiple places begging the question: what happens when these settings conflict?

the simulator had me out in the middle of the North Atlantic!  which explains why the 'country' (as well as several others) were null.  the difficulty lie in setting a test lat/long value and the fact one can do that in multiple places: 1) Edit Scheme, 2) the Simulator Loction menu item, and 3) directly in source.

it would be nice to set test lat/long's in one place and everything then just works.